# How To Improve Security For Simple File Download From A Web Server?

Tags: security, https

Dear StackOverflow community,

======================================

**TL;DR VERSION:**

Before we proceed further in our relationship with a cloud web portal provider, I'd like to insist that they provide us **a secure way to obtain a copy of our data from their web server**.

1. Secure for authenticating ourselves without leaving ourselves vulnerable to having our credentials stolen or spoofed and
2. Secure for the file in transit on its way back to us.

**I suspect I might have to point them in the right direction myself despite my own inexperience in the field.  What kinds of simple-yet-secure approaches to authenticating us could I ask them to look into?**

======================================

**FULL POST**

**BACKGROUND:**

At work, we are evaluating a cloud-based portal through which our current and former customers will be able to network with each other *(we have customers who interact with us in cohorts)*.

The user interface of the portal is well-designed, which is why we're thinking about buying it, but the company providing it is young.  So, for example, their idea of "**helping us integrate our portal data with SalesForce**" was to have a link within the administrative control panel to a page that **returns a CSV file containing the entire contents of our database**.

"Fetch a CSV" actually is fine, because we already do it with other CSV files from our ERP (pushing to SalesForce with a data loader and scheduled Windows batch scripting on an always-on PC).

**I said we could work with it as long as they provided us a way to fetch the CSV file programmatically, without human intervention, at 5AM.  They did so, but the solution seems vulnerable to exploitation and I'd like guidance redirecting their efforts.**

**A DIVERSION ABOUT THE HUMAN UI:**

The link one sees as a human using the web interface to the portal under consideration is http://www.OurBrandedDomain.com/admin/downloaddatabase

If you aren't already logged in, you will be redirected http://www.OurBrandedDomain.com/Admin/login?returnUrl=admin/downloaddatabase , and as soon as you log in, the CSV file will be offered to you.

*(Yes, I know, it's HTTP and it's customer data ... I'm planning to talk to them about turning off HTTP access to the login/signup forms and to the internals of the site, too.  Not the focus of my question, though.)*

**THEIR PROPOSAL:**

So, as I said, I asked for something programmatically usable.

What they gave us was instructions to go to http://www.OurFlavorOfTheirSite.com/admin/fetchdatabase?email=AdminsEmail@Domain.com&password=AdminsPassword

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems like a really insecure way to authenticate ourselves to the web server.

**HOW I NEED HELP:**

Before we proceed further in our relationship with this portal provider, I'd like to insist that they provide us a secure way to obtain a CSV copy of our data.

1. Secure for authenticating ourselves without leaving ourselves vulnerable to having our credentials stolen or spoofed and
2. Secure for the file in transit on its way back to us.

However, I don't get the sense that they've really thought about security much, and I suspect I might have to point them in the right direction myself despite my own inexperience in the field.

**What kinds of simple-yet-secure approaches to authenticating us could I ask them to look into, knowing nothing more about the architecture of their servers than can be inferred from what I've just described here?**

The solution doesn't have to involve us using a browser to interact with their server.  Since we'll be downloading the file in a Windows scripting environment without human intervention, it's fine to suggest solutions that we can only test programmatically *(even though that will make my learning curve a bit steeper)*.

*(I suppose the solution could even get away from the server providing the data in the form of a CSV file, though then we'd probably just end up rebuilding a CSV file locally because we have infrastructure in place for CSV->SalesForce.)*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is insecure.

You should insist on using TLS. For this they need to install a certificate from a Certification Authority to verify that they own the domain `OurFlavorOfTheirSite.com`. This will enable the URL to use HTTPS which means communication is encrypted, and authenticated (i.e. another website cannot spoof `OurFlavorOfTheirSite.com` without a  browser warning being displayed).

Although the `email=AdminsEmail@Domain.com&password=AdminsPassword` parameters will be encrypted, these should be submitted via POST rather than GET. The reason is that GET query string parameters are logged in browser history, logged in proxy and server logs by default and can be transmitted in the `referer` header when resources are included from other domains.